# Can I use Selenium and Nokogiri to locate an element based on a nearby label?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, nokogiri

Let's say I want to scrape the "Weight" attribute from the following content on a website:

```
<div>
  <h2>Details</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><b>Height:</b>6 ft</li>
    <li><b>Weight:</b>6 kg</li>
    <li><b>Age:</b>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

All I want is "6 kg". But it's not labeled, and neither is anything around it. But I know that I always want the text after "Weight:". Is there a way of selecting an element based on the text near it or in it?

In pseudocode, this is what it might look like:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = parsed document
div_of_interest = doc.div where text of h2 == "Details"
element_of_interest = <li> element in div_of_interest with content that contains the string "Weight:"
selected_text = (content in element) minus ("<b>Weight:</b>")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your actual code trials please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the following code

```
p driver.find_elements(xpath: "//li").detect{|li| li.text.include?'Weight'}.text[/:(.*)/,1]
```

output

```
"6 kg"
```

My suggestion is to use WATIR which is wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding where you can easily write the following code

```
p b.li(text: /Weight/).text[/:(.*)/,1]
```

Comment: I have to point to the fact this approach would be very slow - it will cause the webdriver to locate **every** `li` element in the page - 10ms per element, then get its textual value - another 10ms,  just to filter to the one having the target string.

Comment: @Todor True, very true, but with the given structure I don't have any other way to locate that particular element, I need to locate that element by partial text, it doesn't have id,name,class or any other unique locator.

Comment: Shameless plug :) - check my answer, xpath supports locating an element through its textual content.

Comment: @Todor Just saw your answer, sorry, I couldn't check our your answer before I checked out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML.parse(File.read(path_to_file))    
.css("div > ul > li")
.children # get the 'li' items
.each_slice(2) # pair a 'b' item and the text following it
.find{|b, text| b.text == "Weight:"}
.last # extract the text element
.text
```

will return

```
"6 kg"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can locate the element through pure xpath: use the `contains()` function which returns Boolean is its second argument found in the first, and pass to it `text()` (which returns the text of the node) and the target string.

```
xpath_locator = '/div/ul/li[contains(text(), "Weight:")]'
value = driver.find_element(:xpath, xpath_locator).text.partition('Weight:').last
```

Then just get the value after "Weight:".

Comment: Ah! Okay, I haven't seen your answer! Awesome, yes, your answer is the better one. upvoted!